# Getting TLE on Number of Enclaves LeetCode problem

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, breadth-first-search

I encountered the LeetCode problem [1020. Number of Enclaves](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-enclaves/):

> You are given an `m x n` binary matrix `grid`,
> where `0` represents a sea cell and `1` represents a land cell.
> A **move** consists of walking from one land cell to another adjacent
> (**4-directionally**) land cell or walking off the boundary of the `grid`.
>
> Return *the number of land cells in `grid` for which we cannot walk
> off the boundary of the grid in any number of moves.*
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> [image]
>
> **Input:** `grid = [[0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0]]`
> **Output:** `3`
> **Explanation:** There are three 1s that are enclosed by 0s,
> and one 1 that is not enclosed because its on the boundary.
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> [image]
>
> **Input:** `grid = [[0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0]]`
> **Output:** `0`
> **Explanation:** All 1s are either on the boundary or can reach the
> boundary.

I built the following solution using BFS

```
class Solution(object):
    def numEnclaves(self, grid):
        """
        :type grid: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: int
        """

        stack = []
        visited = set()
    
        row_0 = grid[0]
        row_n = grid[-1]
        col_0 = [row[0] for row in grid]
        col_n = [row[-1] for row in grid]
    
        num_rows = len(grid)
        num_cols = len(grid[0])
    
        for col, val in enumerate(row_0):
            if val == 1:
                stack.append([0, col])
                visited.add((0, col))
            
        for col,val in enumerate(row_n):
            if val == 1:
                stack.append([num_rows-1, col])
                visited.add((num_rows-1, col))
    
        for row, val in enumerate(col_0):
            if val == 1:
                stack.append([row, 0])
                visited.add((row, 0))
    
        for row, val in enumerate(col_n):
            if val == 1:
                stack.append([row, num_cols -1])
                visited.add((row, num_cols -1))
           
        while stack:
            row, col = stack.pop(0)
            visited.add((row, col))
        
            steps = [[1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]]
        
            for _row, _col in steps:
                _row += row
                _col += col
            
                if _row <0 or _row > num_rows -1:
                    continue
                
                if _col <0 or _col > num_cols -1:
                    continue
            
                if (_row, _col) in visited:
                    continue
                
                if grid[_row][_col] == 1:
                    stack.append([_row, _col])
    
        result = 0
        for row in range(1, num_rows-1):
            for col in range(1, num_cols -1):
                if grid[row][col] == 1 and (row,col) not in visited:
                    result += 1
            
        return result
```

My solution works fine for smaller inputs, however it fails for larger values ex: a grid of size 200x200. I fail to understand what might be causing the TLE in the solution, or how I can optimise it further?

Comment: Convert the islands connected to the boundaries to `0` and then just count the number of islands (groups of `1`).  So in your first eg., the yellow cell will become `0` since it is connected to a boundary.

Comment: @Someone but how is that improving the time complexity from the solution ?

Comment: explain what TLE means. Not everyone uses leetcode

Comment: @phuclv time limit exceeded

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is using a set in order to find if a node was visited - but this is not necessary since you can simply put a marker on the node saying you visited it. For example let's say `2` stands for visited from now on:

```py
class Solution2(object):
    def numEnclaves(self, grid):
        """
        :type grid: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: int
        """

        stack = []

        num_rows = len(grid)
        num_cols = len(grid[0])

        for row in range(len(grid)):
            if grid[row][0] == 1:
                stack.append((row, 0))
                # 2 means visited from now on
                grid[row][0] = 2

            if grid[row][num_cols - 1] == 1:
                stack.append((row, 0))
                grid[row][num_cols - 1] = 2

        for col in range(len(grid[0])):
            if grid[0][col] == 1:
                stack.append((0, col))
                grid[0][col] = 2

            if grid[num_rows - 1][col] == 1:
                stack.append((0, col))
                grid[num_rows - 1][col] = 2

        while len(stack) != 0:
            row, col = stack.pop(0)

            steps = [[1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]]

            for _row, _col in steps:
                _row += row
                _col += col

                if _row < 0 or _row > num_rows - 1:
                    continue

                if _col < 0 or _col > num_cols - 1:
                    continue

                if grid[_row][_col] == 2:
                    continue

                if grid[_row][_col] == 1:
                    stack.append((_row, _col))
                    grid[_row][_col] = 2

        result = 0
        for row in range(1, num_rows - 1):
            for col in range(1, num_cols - 1):
                if grid[row][col] == 1:
                    result += 1

        return result
```

The time drops dramatically and the tests you gave in the question still passes. You should know that a set access is not really `O(1)` if the set size is very big.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you do not mark cells as visited the moment you put them on `stack` (which really is a queue). This means that the stack will have duplicate cells, which slows down the process.

As mentioned by others, you can use the grid itself for marking cells as visited, but I would just wipe out the 1 that you visit (to 0). Then at the end you only need to *sum* all cell values.

Some other things:

- Only define `steps` once, not inside the loop;
- Use `sum` to get the final count;
- Avoid putting corner cells twice on the initial queue
- Use operator chaining for checking that row and column are in range

Suggested code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def numEnclaves(self, grid):
        num_rows = len(grid)
        num_cols = len(grid[0])
    
        queue = [
            (0, col) for col, val in enumerate(grid[0]) if val == 1
        ] + [
            (num_rows-1, col) for col,val in enumerate(grid[-1]) if val == 1
        ] + [
            (row+1, 0) for row, val in enumerate(grid[1:-1]) if val[0] == 1
        ] + [
            (row+1, num_cols-1) for row, val in enumerate(grid[1:-1]) if val[-1] == 1
        ]
        for row, col in queue:
            grid[row][col] = 0
        steps = [[1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]]
        while queue:
            row, col = queue.pop(0)        
            for _row, _col in steps:
                _row += row
                _col += col
                if 0 <= _row < num_rows and 0 <= _col < num_cols and grid[_row][_col] == 1:
                    grid[_row][_col] = 0
                    queue.append((_row, _col))

        return sum(sum(grid[row]) for row in range(1, num_rows-1))
```